# framework7 prevent caching pages data

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, html-framework-7

i want to prevent all the app`s pages cache in Framework 7. is there any option i can add here

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
        material: true //enable Material theme
    })
```

or a function that can make me stop caching permanently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may set `cache: false` as in

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    cache: false /* disable caching */
})
```

or (if it's fitter for your application) you may set its duration to zero setting `cacheDuration: 0` as in

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    cacheDuration: 0 /* set caching expire time to 0 */
})
```

You can refer to http://framework7.io/docs/init-app.html for more detailed specs.

Answer (score 2):

for preventing cache you can use inline method  (data-page attribute)

```
data-ignore-cache="true"

<a href="#" data-ignore-cache="true"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> sample link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to define a variable timestamp and set it with Date.now() and give it to route path parameter with ?timestamp on every route path ending.

So in this case framework7 must load every html file on every browser reload again.

after your development and design is finished you can comment it out. This scenario you can use for every framework you use. it is not framework7 specific.

**for examle:**

```
var timestamp   = Date.now();

routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    url: './index.html?'+timestamp,
  },
  {
    path: '/about/',
    url: './pages/about.html?'+timestamp,
  },
  {
    path: '/form/',
    url: './pages/form.html?'+timestamp,
  },
  {
    path: '/page-loader-template7/:user/:userId/:posts/:postId/',
    templateUrl: './pages/page-loader-template7.html?'+timestamp,
  },
  {
    path: '/page-loader-component/:user/:userId/:posts/:postId/',
    componentUrl: './pages/page-loader-component.html?'+timestamp
  }]
```

Comment: If you do it like that, won't your cache get clogged with all the pages with the different timestamps?